# cakephp custom class or helper?

Tags: php, cakephp

I currently have a writers MVC that is working. I have a firstname and lastname property. On the index I want to display the full name. I understand that this can be done several ways.

I can write the logic in the view

```
echo $writer['Writer']['firstname'] . " " . $writer['Writer']['lastname'];
```

I can write a helper function to do this and keep my view clean. This is how I currently do it.

```
echo fullName($writer['Writer']['firstname'], $writer['Writer']['lastname']);
```

I was wondering however if it would be a better to create a writer class that has a fullname method. Then I could simplify my view a bit more.

```
echo $writer->fullname
```

So, I know how to write helpers and this works, assuming that building a class is the way to go, when is the right time, after a query to instantiate each object? I assume in the controller. Further, where would my class reside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a helper CustomHelper (anything you like) in your `View/Helper/`.
Then a method fullName:

```
 public function fullName($writer) {
    return $writer['first_name'] . ' ' . $writer['last_name'];
 }

// in your view
echo h($this->Custom->fullName($writer['Writer']));
```

You can also make a behavior to format in on find() already.
It depends where you are going to use it. If it is only view related, helpers would suffice. If you need it at controller/model level you might want to use the model layer to concatenate.

Comment: Thanks, Sometimes seeing something is the best teacher. I never knew I could pass $writer['Writer'] and still have access to all the details.

Comment: you could also just pass $writer and access it including the Model name. If you need to do cross model stuff that would be the best solution then. also note the h() to secure your views by escaping the name.

Comment: Mark thanks again, you initial post spurred on some more searching but helped guide me in the direction I needed (model virtual field)

Comment: well, i thought about virtual fields too, but I usually like to use smart methods to concatenate, therefore behavior etc. what if the lastname is empty, etc. than you dont want the extra space. i find the virtual field here too restrictive in logic.

Comment: So here is what I have for a virtual field. I thought about the no last name piece and thought Trim would take care of that.  
`public $virtualFields = array('full_name' => 'trim(CONCAT(Writer.firstname, " ", Writer.lastname))');`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to create a virtual field in your Writer model:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'full_name'=>"CONCAT(Writer.first_name, ' ', Writer.last_name)"
);
```

And output it with:

```
echo h($writer['Writer']['full_name']);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I went with. Thank you everyone! Mark's post led me down the path of "you might want to use the model layer to concatenate."